# Chrome Extension: Use a function on options.js into background.js

Tags: function, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to call a function being at options.js (being executed at the option page of the extension) from background.js (being executed as the background page of the extension) ?

The special need is that this function returns a value (string) that needs to be passed as a variable. I could do this, if the function was local:

```
myvar = myfun();
```

but how would I assing the value returned from myfun() to myvar if myvar is a variable needed in background.js and myfun() is a function of options.js?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use `chrome.extension.getViews()` function. It will return window object of all opened extension pages. You can filter out the options page easily by checking some variable. See documentation [here](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension.html#method-getViews).